# android glance widget - does not work when changing its code, needs to be removed and added again

Tags: android, glance-appwidget, glance

in an android app we have a couple of app widgets, implemented using Jetpack Glance.

whenever there is a code change - like a really simple change - upon running the app, the widget just shows a waiting wheel. in order to see the change, i need to remove the widget and add it again.

i tried with a simple widget:

```
class MyWidget : GlanceAppWidget(), KoinComponent {
override suspend fun provideGlance(context: Context, id: GlanceId) {
    provideContent {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
}
```

}

changing the text to "Hello World 123" would generate the problem.
this costs a lot of time for simple changes. i do not want to use preview since i am testing and making last changes on the device.

thanks.

added:
android:initialLayout is shown, upon rerunning the app.

Comment: Can you provide what version of Glance you are using as well as what device you are testing on? 

How are you updating your widget after the application relaunches?

Quick testing on a Pixel 7a, Pixel Tablet, and Pixel 8 AOSP emulator all update as expected for me.

Comment: it works, when making sure that the widget state gets changed before update: GlanceAppWidgetManager(application).getGlanceIds(glanceId).forEach { glanceId ->
            updateAppWidgetState(application, PreferencesGlanceStateDefinition, glanceId) { prefs ->
                prefs.toMutablePreferences().apply { this[stringPreferencesKey(AppConstants.UPDATE_WIDGET_TIME_KEY)] = time }
            }
        }
MyWidget().updateAll(application)